# Basis of a free module under module homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-modules

Hello people my question is the following: Let R be a principal ideal domain, F be a free R-module with basis {e1,…,eN} and f:F→F a module homomorphism.The R-submodule imf of F is always free since we are working over PID. Is there any case that the set {f(e1),…,f(eN)} does not form a base of imf? It is obvious that the images of the basis element through f generate Imf, so all result to whether these elements could be linearly dependent over R. thanks in advance!

Comment: A generating set is always mapped to a generating set of the image of a morphism. But if $f$ is not injective, then why should $f(e_1),\dotsc,f(e_N)$ still be a basis?

Answer (score 1):

Let $R=k$ be a field, $F=k^3$, $e_i$ the standard basis, $f=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Then the $f(e_i)$ are no basis of the image of $f$ since they are linearly dependent.

Comment: I see, thanks for the counter example. However I notice that the determinant of the matrix is 0.  If it was non-zero the endomorphism would be invertible since K is a field and f(ei) a basis of Imf=F
Would anything change in my original question, if one supposes that the matrix of endomorphism has non zero determinant??

Comment: @noname Probably not since you stated that you are working over a PID, so your determinant cannot become a zero divisor.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help !!